# Compressor Break In Help

Tags: compressor

I received my new compressor today. The break-in instructions say:

> PREPARATION FOR STARTING
>
> Push in switch to OFF position, and plug in power cord at the wall.
>
> Pull up the red power switch and run compressor unit for 30 minutes to
>   break in the pump parts.
>
> Turn regulator knob fully counterclockwise to cause air to bleed off.
>
> Attach the hose and tool to the compressor using the Euro type quick
>   release couplings on the compressor.

The problem is about 30 seconds after starting the compressor it shuts off because it has reached the maximum pressure.

[Here are the instructions](http://www.sgs-engineering.com/media/manuals/SC6H.pdf).

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please ask only one question per post. Yes, you can leave air in the compressor between uses, but you need to drain the accumulated moisture regularly per the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The third step in your instructions might address this

> Turn regulator knob fully counterclockwise to cause air to bleed off.

so either that or leave the drain cock twisted open while it's running.

Answer (score 0):

The break-in period is probably to allow the seals to seat. If the compressor is operating well, I wouldn't worry about it. 30 minutes of use will pass before long anyway.

Otherwise, you'd obviously need to allow air to escape somehow. Either remove the quick-connector from the output nipple, or attach a device that you can keep open, such as a blower nozzle.

Comment: Just open the drain valve if you need the air to escape